# How to setup MVC mock.Setup and.Returns for a repository method, which has on out parameter and a return type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, model-view-controller, moq

I need to mock a method in a repository, but the method has an out parameter and a return type (of type class ExBool, which sets statuses and error messages).
It needs to return a list of account setups.
These setups are applied to the data posted back from the view.
I would have preferred getting the real values (accountSetups) ex the Dbase, but seems I will need to create dummy values in the mock of that repository.
So, the question is how do I set dummy values into the retrieved 'accountSetups'?

the test method will test whether the incoming concatenated string is in the format as specified by the accountsetups.

The repository (which is injected into a controller (with Ninject)):

```
public interface IAccountSetupBo
{
    ExBool List(out List<AccountSetup> accountSetups);
}
```

My Test:

```
ExBool result = new ExBool();  // this is the method's return type
private List<AccountSetup> accountSetups;  //This is the list of setups reurned by the 'out' parameter, in the List method.

[TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        // Inject with Mock, which creates a proxy..not a concrete instance
        mockedAccountSetupBo = new Mock<IAccountSetupBo>();
        mockedAccountSetupBo
            .Setup(x => x.List(out accountSetups))
            .Returns(result);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: populate the collection prior to the setup and it will lazy evaluated when the model is invoked.

Comment: Show the subject under test and how it uses the dependency that is being mocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way could be to use `delegate` in the `Callback` hook provided by **`moq`**. Something like this:

```
public delegate void SetupOutList(out List<AccountSetup> a);

mockedAccountSetupBo
        .Setup(x => x.List(out It.Ref<List<AccountSetup>>.IsAny))
        .Callback(new SetupOutList((out List<AccountSetup> a) => 
        {
            a = new List<AccountSetup>{...}; // initialize your list
        })
        .Returns(result);
```

---

Take a look at the official documentation about the [callbacks](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#callbacks).

Answer (score 1):

populate the collection prior to the setup

```
ExBool result = new ExBool();  // this is the method's return type

[TestInitialize]
public void SetUp() {

    List<AccountSetup> accountSetups = new List<AccountSetup>() {
        //...populate with desired objects
    }

    // Inject with Mock, which creates a proxy..not a concrete instance
    mockedAccountSetupBo = new Mock<IAccountSetupBo>();
    mockedAccountSetupBo
        .Setup(x => x.List(out accountSetups))
        .Returns(result);
}
```

and it will lazy evaluated when the model is invoked.